# How to display image ALT under image in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, image, alt

In each WordPress post, I have ~10 images with unique alt. How to display under each image ALT as a visible text? Maybe as description or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using a custom theme or something if am to do it I will do it this way " alt="">

Hopefully, that solves the problem.

Comment: I think you don't understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

alt is  for describing whats on image, if you want add to image use `figcaption` stricture should be like this

```
<figure>
 <img src="" alt=""/>
 <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```